# External API call with next step or rollback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following functionality to implement:

The method makes a call to an external API with POST (create operation) request. If the creation is valid, the next step is to create a bucket in S3. If the first step fails, whole method should thrown an exception.

What I came up with:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> foo(String name) {
   String requestEntity = //....
   try {
   ResponseEntity resp =
            new RestTemplate().exchange("http://localhost:8080/rest/someservice",
                    HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
       if (resp.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
           myBucket.makeBucket(requestEntity); 

           return new ResponseEntity<>(/*Some success message*/);
       } else return new ResponseEntity<>(/*Some error message*/);
   } catch (RestClientException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(/*Some error message*/);
   }
}
```

Is it a valid solution or perhaps I should do it differently ie. with `CompletableFuture`?

Comment: It has to be synchronous so this solution is the valid one. CompleteableFuture would make it async which is not what u want

Comment: This method should returns the result to the caller so it's a synchronous one. In this case you don't have use any asynchronous way. The current manner is valid.